# How to invoke client side validation on vue-multiselect component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I am using the [vue-multiselect library](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) like so:

> in `src/components/FeedbackForm.vue`

```
<div>
<CustomerSelect :required="true" />
</div
```

Question: How can I make this select component required on the client-side? I thought I would be able to simply add an HTML5 attribute like so:

> in `src/components/CustomerSelect.vue`

template section:

```
<multiselect
  id="customer_last_name_input"
  v-model="c_lastname_value"
  :options="getActiveUserProfiles"
  label="lastname"
  track-by="uid"
  :close-on-select="true"
  @select="onSelect"
  @remove="onRemove"
  required <----------can't do this?
>
```

script section:

```
props: ['required']
```

Doing the above code does not invoke client-side validation in the browser like a regular HTML select element. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for [docs](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-props) it accepts a `allowEmpty`bool prop.

> allowEmpty || Boolean || Allows to remove all selected values.
> Otherwise one must be left selected.

so it would be

```
<multiselect
  id="customer_last_name_input"
  v-model="c_lastname_value"
  :options="getActiveUserProfiles"
  label="lastname"
  track-by="uid"
  :close-on-select="true"
  @select="onSelect"
  @remove="onRemove"
  :allow-empty="required"  <----------do this?
>
```